# C# selenium find all links within page only outputting 24 links

Tags: c#, selenium

So I'm trying to output every link within the page, but it's only outputting 24 everytime? when there's over 50+? is it possible the function is running before page is completely loaded?

```
                foreach (var item in driver.FindElements(By.TagName("img")))
                {
                   string itemlist = item.GetAttribute("src");
                   Console.WriteLine(itemlist);
                }
```

Comment: There is a difference between img and a tags. Links have tagname <a> and <img> are images.

Comment: In that page contains more than 50 img

Comment: Yes I'm referring to the img links :)

Comment: What is the number returned by jQuery? `$('img').length`

Comment: I think it is possible that the page is being loaded dynamically (for example, load images when scrolling down the page)

Comment: Update the question with relevant _HTML_ please.